# If $X$ is a integrable random variable (discrete or continuous) $E(X \mid Y)$ is finite

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, expected-value

How can you prove that if $X$ is an integrable variable, then the $E(X 
\mid Y)$ is finite regardless of whether the variable $X$ is continuous or discrete?

The problem is: Proof that if $X$ is an integrable variable, then $E(X \mid Y)$ is finite. Additionally, proof $E\bigl( E(X \mid Y) \bigr) = E(X)$. The second part, I don't have problem, but I have very problems for proof that $E(X \mid Y)$ is finite.

If $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables:

$$E(X \mid Y=y) = \sum_{x}x\left(P(X=x \mid Y=y)\right)  = \sum_{x}\left(x\left(\frac{P\left(X \;=\; x \;,\; Y\; =\; y\right)}{P(Y\; =\; y)}\right)\right)$$

If $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables:

$$E(X \mid Y=y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\left(f_{X|Y=y}\left(y\right)\right)\;   dy= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(x\left(\frac{f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)}{f_{X}\left(x\right)}\right)\right) dy$$

Comment: Are you allowed to know and use the law of iterated expectations?

Comment: This question cannot be  answered unless you tell us what you know about conditional expectations. In particular what is your definition of $E(X|Y)$?

Comment: @kimchilover He is asking about finiteness of $E(X|Y)$ not its expectation. The question is about the very definition of conditional expectation.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy One way to show a rv. is finite with probability 1 is to show that it is integrable.

Comment: @kimchilover Sure, but that comes only after you know the definition. I think in any definition of conditional expectation finiteness is obvious.

Comment: The problem is: Proof that if X is an integrable variable, then E(X|Y) is finite regardless of whether the variable X is continuous or discrete. Aditional, proof E(E(X|Y))=E(X).  The second part, I don't have problem, but I have very problems for proof that E(X|Y) is finite.